# user device detection with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

my html:

```
<li data-memberId="{$row['member_id']}"></li>
```

I want to show user device Icon behind of usernames. for this I write below javascript code but I don't know how to implement that.

my javascript:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)").matches)
{
  document.write("fa-mobile");  
}  
else  
{  
  document.write("fa-desktop");  
}
```

just I want to display user device (mobile or desktop or tablet)

Comment: you can not conclude from the width of the browser if it is a mobile, tablet or desktop device. There are low resolution monitors and high resolution smartphones. One thing that works for most cases is to check for touch devices. There are only few desktops with touch screen (and they mostly have high resolutions). Also better check for `device.width` instead of browser-`width`. Another way is to check for the browser. There only few desktop users who use a mobile browser through an emulator.

Comment: _"I want to show user device Icon behind of usernames."_ - you mean as a list of multiple, different users? Well that of course can't be done using only client-side JavaScript code that runs in the browser, in the first place. (If you are user A, that is currently viewing this display, and you look at the record for user B - then the JavaScript code would still be running in _your_ browser, only able to determine what kind of device _you_ are currently using to view this.)

Comment: What is the purpose of telling users what you think their own device is?

Comment: I want to add user's device behind of her name.

Comment: Then you would have to query that information for user X, when user X is actually _viewing_ your page - and then _store_ this info somewhere permanently, like in a database. (And of course that would only give you the information, which device they used to access your site _last_. Or you would have to _add_ to the list of the user's used devices, every time they access your site with a new one/new "type". But then you'd probably end up with a lot of users that have used a desktop one time, and a mobile another. Questionable, what benefit having this info then eventually would still have.)

Answer (score 1):

You can get various Information with `navigator.userAgent` about the users device and browser. Read more [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgent)

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  document.write("fa-mobile");
} else {
  document.write("fa-desktop");
}
```